# .htaccess redirect keeping number from old URL in new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am creating a large number of 301 redirects, obviously pointing old URLs to new URLs with the following code schema in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^socialhire/career--interview-advice/11/radical-thinking--market-yourself-to-a-recruiter/?$ http://www.bold-identities.com/socialhire/blog/candidate/radical-thinking--market-yourself-to-a-recruiter/  [L,R=301]
```

However, when I go to the old URL I am redirected here:

`/socialhire/blog/candidate/11/radical-thinking--market-yourself-to-a-recruiter/`

Why is the redirect keeping the number from the old URL?

I have around 2000 redirects all acting the same. Here's a [link](http://www.bold-identities.com/socialhire/htaccess.php) to the whole `.htaccess`

Comment: Could any other rule be affecting it? It looks like another rule is putting that 11 in there

Comment: Yes and probably on the new site, the one being redirected to. Look at your rules there or it may be a function of your CMS on that site. You can see exactly what's happening by putting `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` in your server config and then checking the logs, although it can't go in .htaccess.

Comment: There are these rules earlier in the .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^blog/?$ pages/blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/blog-post.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/blog.php?cat=$1 [L]
`

Could these picking up that number and putting it in there? If so, how would I stop it from happening?

Thanks guys

Comment: Here's a link to the entire contents, sorry to post twice in a row:

[link](http://www.bold-identities.com/socialhire/htaccess.php)

Comment: It must be something on the bold-identities site, not on the site the redirect is coming from.

Comment: What is the intent of the `?` at the end of your pattern?  I am guessing you want to specify an optional trailing slash?  If so, that's not correct.  If not - well that's still not a correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a looping or double redirect. From the Apache Docs on flags: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

> It is therefore important, if you are using RewriteRule directives in one of these contexts, that you take explicit steps to avoid rules looping, and not count solely on the [L] flag to terminate execution of a series of rules, as shown below.
>   An alternative flag, [END], can be used to terminate not only the current round of rewrite processing but prevent any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context. This does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

I would recommend using the [END] flag as well as R,L

Comment: Thanks for your reply - adding [END] results in a 500 Error. Even if I remove all other lines from the .htaccess and just leave the Rewrite that isn't working then it still does the same thing, so I have concluded that it is not caused by earlier rules.